# How can I register a custom form field type in Silex / Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig, silex

My App ist running, but when I use a custom Form-Field-Type (shtumi_daterange) like:

```
public function buildForm(\Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $dateRange4 = new DateRange('m/d/Y');
    $dateRange4->parseData('03/27/2012 - 04/05/2012');
    $builder->add('builddate', "shtumi_daterange", array('required'=>false, 'default'=>$dateRange4));
}
```

the this error occurs:

```
Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\FormException' with 
message 'Could not load type "shtumi_daterange"' in 
../vendor/symfony/form/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRegistry.php:95
```

I think, I need something like:

```
<?php
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path'        => $path_ext_dir_abs . '/views',
'twig.form.templates' => array('form_div_layout_custom.html.twig'),
    'form.type.shtumi_daterange' => 'Shtumi\UsefulBundle\Form\Type\DateRangeType',
));
```

but I just dont know/find the right symtax!

From the [symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html), I found this example how to register a custom form field type, but I can't transform this to get it run with silex:

```
services:

  form.type.gender:
      class: Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type\GenderType
      arguments:
          - "%genders%"
      tags:
          - { name: form.type, alias: gender }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to register it to be able to use it. You can pass a new instance as the second parameter of `add`:

```
use Shtumi\UsefulBundle\Form\Type\DateRangeType;
/* ... */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $dateRange4 = new DateRange('m/d/Y');
    $dateRange4->parseData('03/27/2012 - 04/05/2012');
    $builder->add('builddate', new DateRangeType(), array('required'=>false, 'default'=>$dateRange4));
}
```

It's mentioned in the [document you linked](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#using-the-field-type).

Answer (score 3):

I achieved this by extending the `FormServiceProvider`.

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface;

$app->extend('form.factory', function (FormFactoryInterface $factory) {
    $factory->addType(new MyType());

    return $factory;
});
```

Comment: addType() is deprecated since version 2.1 and will be removed in 2.3. Use form extensions or type registration in the Dependency Injection Container instead.