# How can I make the entity field type available in silex?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, silex

I have been using Silex for my latest project and I was trying to follow along with the ["How to Dynamically Modify Forms Using Form Events"](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-user-data) in the Symfony cookbook. I got to the part that uses the entity field type and realized it is not available in Silex.

It looks like the symfony/doctrine-bridge can be added to my composer.json which contains the "EntityType". Has anyone successfully got entity type to work in Silex or run into this issue and found a workaround?

I was thinking something like this might work:

```
    $builder
        ->add('myentity', new EntityType($objectManager, $queryBuilder, 'Path\To\Entity'), array(
    ))
    ;
```

I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12619255/1814739) which looks like it might do the trick by extending the form.factory but haven't attempted yet.

Comment: Did you get it o work on `Silex 2.0~`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [this](https://gist.github.com/umpirsky/3939837) Gist to add EntityType field in Silex.

But the trick is register the `DoctrineOrmExtension` form extension by extending `form.extensions` like [FormServiceProvider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/form.html) doc says.

`DoctrineOrmExtension` expects an `ManagerRegistry` interface in its constructor, that can be implemented extending `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\AbstractManagerRegistry` as the follow:

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace\Form\Extensions\Doctrine\Bridge;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\AbstractManagerRegistry;
use Silex\Application;

/**
 * References Doctrine connections and entity/document managers.
 *
 * @author Саша Стаменковић <umpirsky@gmail.com>
 */
class ManagerRegistry extends AbstractManagerRegistry
{

    /**
     * @var Application
     */
    protected $container;

    protected function getService($name)
    {
        return $this->container[$name];

    }

    protected function resetService($name)
    {
        unset($this->container[$name]);

    }

    public function getAliasNamespace($alias)
    {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException('Namespace aliases not supported.');

    }

    public function setContainer(Application $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container['orm.ems'];

    }

}
```

So, to register the form extension i use:

```
// Doctrine Brigde for form extension
$app['form.extensions'] = $app->share($app->extend('form.extensions', function ($extensions) use ($app) {
    $manager = new MyNamespace\Form\Extensions\Doctrine\Bridge\ManagerRegistry(
        null, array(), array('default'), null, null, '\Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\Proxy'
    );
    $manager->setContainer($app);
    $extensions[] = new Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\DoctrineOrmExtension($manager);

    return $extensions;
}));
```

Comment: I had to add "symfony/dependency-injection": "~2.3" to my composer.json. Worked great, thank you!